# JWT Issue with Docusign API

Tags: docusignapi, jwt

We generated JWT using docusign given private key and validated by Docusign public key in jwt.io site. It generated valid signature.

Using same signature we called Docusign demo server for access token

`POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token`

with

```
grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion=Signature generated
```

but getting error "Invalid Grant".

What could be the possible reason? If signature is already verified in jwt.io with public key, Docusign should accept the assertion value.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question to add in your current code. See [ask] for help on how to edit this question.

Answer (score 0):

[As documented](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken), you also need to supply the following claims:

- iss--The integration key (also known as client ID) of the application.
- sub--The user ID of the user to be impersonated.
- iat--The DateTime when the JWT was issued, in Unix epoch format.
- exp--The DateTime when the JWT assertion will expire, in Unix epoch format. Use 1 hour after iat or less.
- aud--domain name of the authentication service instance to be used. For demo environments, use `account-d.docusign.com` For production environments, use `account.docusign.com`. Note: Do not include https:// in the aud value!
- scope--The scopes being requested. For the JWT bearer grant, the requested scope should be `signature`.

See the docs and also see the DocuSign JWT code examples, the [repos named eg-01-*](https://github.com/docusign?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=in%3Aname%20eg-01-&type=&language=)

Ask a **new question** if you'd like further help.

Comment: Hi Larry,I passed above information only as part of claims but it didn't work out. Is it something else I need to pass on?

Comment: @VikrantNehra, please start with one of the code examples, get it working, then reverse engineer/compare with your code to figure out the issue.